# Angular UI datepicker popup open without ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

According to official Angular UI documentation for datepicker users in popup style I need to create additional button with `ng-click` event on it to change `$scope` property which was binded to `is-open` attribute like so:

```
  <p class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
     <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
     </span>
  </p>
```

In my application it is possible to have more than 10 such datepickers per view so I need to implement property for `is-open` attribute per each.

Is there any way to open datepicker popup without `is-open` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have +10 datepickers and repeat the same markup over and over, and need to create `$scope` functions without any real purpose - then it is almost screaming for a directive to do the trivial tasks! The markup you are repeating can be placed in a template :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dateAutomater.html">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </button>
  </span>     
</script>
```

The directive (the very basics) could look like this :

```
.directive('dateAutomater', ['$compile',  function($compile) {
  return {       
    transclude: true,        
    templateUrl: 'dateAutomater.html',
    restrict: 'AE',                   
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
      $scope.dateInfo = $scope.dateInfo || {};
      var dateInfo = $scope.dateInfo,
          input = element.find('input'),    
          button = element.find('button'),    
          name = input.name || 'date'+Object.keys($scope.dateInfo).length,
          info = {
            open: false,
            click: function() {
              this.open = true
            }
          }   

      dateInfo[name] = info;
      input.attr('ng-model', attrs.dateAutomater);
      input.attr('uib-datepicker-popup', 'dd-MMMM-yyyy');
      input.attr('is-open', 'dateInfo[\"'+name+'\"].open')
      button.attr('ng-click', 'dateInfo[\"'+name+'\"].click()');

      $compile(element.contents())($scope);
    }   
  } 
}])
```

It simply takes the `model` as argument, injects the markup from the template and bind the important variable `is-open` and `ng-click` function to a self maintained object, `$scope.dateInfo`. Usage

```
<p class="input-group" date-automater="dt"></p>
<p class="input-group" date-automater="date"></p>        
<p class="input-group" date-automater="yesterDay"></p> 
...
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/H6hgYdF420R4IKdjCBGM?p=preview**

Now expand the directive / template to set other default properties you want on the datepicker, like `min-date` and so on.

Comment: Nice solution, Thanks! But when I tried to add date-picker-options it seems not working

Comment: Hey @Anton - "_I tried to add date-picker-options it seems not working_" - what exactly did you do ...?  Perhaps I can help.

Comment: Just added configuration object and attribute for it. You can check -> http://plnkr.co/edit/N5jwYkfvVv4fkxWEhY2G?p=preview